# Convert DAX column into power query (add column)

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I have this column which I use for scoring/ranking across varius type of FRUIT sold. It works really well, I'm moving into a bigger dataset and I want to see if I can move this directly into power query...

How do I write the code in the 'add column' in power query? - is it at all possible?

Normal column calculation:

```
COLUMN NAME = 
VAR NCT = TEST[Fruit]
VAR filteredTable = FILTER ( TEST, NOT ( ISBLANK ( TEST[Sold amount] ) ) && TEST[Fruit] = NCT)

RETURN
IF(ISBLANK(TEST[Sold amount]),BLANK(),
DIVIDE (
RANKX (
filteredTable,
TEST[Sold amount],
,
ASC
) - 1,
COUNTROWS ( filteredTable ) - 1
))*100
```

Test data is here:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/trrdggjz4c1x3ff/Test_scoringrank_in_powerquery.pbix?dl=0

Comment: Could you please describe in words exactly what you want in this calculated column.

Comment: Hi @RonRosenfeld,

Yes I would like to have this column directly in my model (power query) instead of a column I have add'ed in the desktop of powerBI.

When I press transformatino, there is a function called "add column", but the language seems different compared to the column code I have in the desktop

Comment: I think Ron means please describe what this code is doing -- the functionality you want to replicate, not why you want it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I finally figured out what you are doing.

You can't do it by adding a Custom Column, but there is another way.
Power Query lacks the `RANKX` function so you have to write a custom function.

Instead of the `FILTER` on each row, in PQ you would do a `GroupBy` and then execute the custom RANK function on each subGroup.

The DAX `RANKX` function as you have written it, is a `skipRank` type of function with regard to ties.  Also taken into account was not ranking the entries where `Sales Amount` was blank.

For the custom Rank function

- Sort each sub-group Ascending
- Assign a serial number to each amount (unless the amount is blank = *null* in PQ)
- Then Group each subgroup by Amount, and extract the Min Rank from that for the tied rankings.
- Expand the tables.

Other steps are housekeeping.

Hopefully I have annotated the code sufficiently that you will be able to understand.

***Custom Function***

- Add as blank query
- Rename `fnScoringRank`

```
(tbl as table, colToRank as text)=>
    
let 
    #"Sort by colRank" = Table.Sort(tbl,{colToRank,Order.Ascending}),
    colRank = List.Buffer(Table.Column(#"Sort by colRank", colToRank)),
    
    #"Add Rank Col" = 
        Table.FromColumns(
            Table.ToColumns(#"Sort by colRank") &     
                {List.Accumulate(colRank,{}, (state,current)=>
                        if current=null then state & {null} 
                            else if List.Max(state) = null then state & {0} 
                            else state & {List.Max(state)+1})},
            Table.ColumnNames(#"Sort by colRank") & {"Rank"}),

    #"Group by colToRank" = Table.Group(#"Add Rank Col",{colToRank},{
        {"all",each _, type table},
        {"Scoring Rank", each List.Min([Rank])/(Table.RowCount(tbl)-1)*100, type number}
    }),

    //remove unneeded column and expand table
    #"Remove Column" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Group by colToRank",colToRank),
    eXpand = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Remove Column","all", 
        List.RemoveMatchingItems(Table.ColumnNames(#"Sort by colRank"),{"Rank"})),
    types = List.Zip({Table.ColumnNames(eXpand),{type text, type text, type text, Int64.Type, Int64.Type, type number}}),
    typeIt = Table.TransformColumnTypes(eXpand, types)
in  
   typeIt
```

***Main Query***

```
let

//Next two lines are from your code
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("XZBBD4IwDIX/y85cDDC8olET0EiyI+HQ6CILUEgRE/31bovG1cvW9Xvre1tdi3yaei0icTKd2/JlvpMBW8WiiWpxJsCbA+WIBFemSLmi8s0fzlLpBZUGsseuB+KClcffAKoFxBFttbcTL66VcINibBnm83cPYHfjECoz8NGxzJh7YQa7HjQNgE9brTP59zpYeqZIk9Bg25KZOZdMcDQvhpNP+m+AjdaEQO6H1QQGvYRHUMsMGHCZhgYlkAlpEluD5g0=", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [Fruit = _t, #"Account ID" = _t, Country = _t, #"Sold amount" = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Fruit", type text}, {"Account ID", type text}, {"Country", type text}, {"Sold amount", Int64.Type}}),

//Add index column to remember original order
    #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Changed Type", "Orig Order", 0, 1, Int64.Type),

//Group by fruit
//   Then run custom rank function on each sub-group
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Added Index", {"Fruit"}, {
        {"Count", each fnScoringRank(_, "Sold amount")}}),

//Remove unneeded column and expand the table resulting from custom function
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Grouped Rows",{"Fruit"}),
    #"Expanded Count" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Columns", "Count", 
        {"Fruit", "Account ID", "Country", "Sold amount", "Orig Order", "Scoring Rank"}),

//Sort back to original order
//  Remove the sorting column
//  Set the data types
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Expanded Count",{{"Orig Order", Order.Ascending}}),
    #"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Sorted Rows",{"Orig Order"}),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Removed Columns1",{{"Fruit", type text}, {"Account ID", type text}, {"Country", type text}, {"Sold amount", Int64.Type}, {"Scoring Rank", type number}})
in
    #"Changed Type1"
```

***Results from your data***
[image]